# oracle nvl and not in function in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to implement below oracle logic in spark 1.5.0, I have select query like

Ex:

```
select name, id, age, country, CASE WHEN (id is not null AND NVL(country,'DUMMY') NOT IN (us,'DUMMY') )
THEN correct 
ELSE wrong
END Code(one of the column)
from employee
```

.

I want to implement the case and NVL logic in spark Can someone help me how to implement this logic in spark scala API by using dataframes.

Comment: nvl functions are supported in the Spark sql. As far as Exists is concerned not about that.

Comment: @RajatMishra Can you please point to where the NVL functions are supported in Spark SQL. I have now spent 30m trying every way I can think of to find documentation showing how to use them.

Answer (score -1):

df:
id,description,value
1,"something","its there"
2,"nothing",null

sql:
select id,description,nvl(value,'N') from df;

result:
id,description,value
1,'something','it is there'
2,'nothing','N'

testing in spark 2.1.0